# Considering of two phase commits on sharded clusters

Tags: mongodb

I've been using MongoDB for my application and I need to use 'two-phase commits'.

I'm wondering, is there any possibility encountering with an issue/pitfall when using two-phase commits on sharded clusters? Or should I stop to use two-phase commits right now?

https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/